MATE Applications menu GUI under 24.04 upgrade wrong
I upgraded 22.04 to 24.04 using the Software Updater GUI (24.04.1 upgrade release).  The system is stock Ubuntu with MATE installed as the end-user GUI.  I upgraded by the CLI command in a terminal window some applications after the machine restarted, such as UCSF Chimera, using packages supplied by the application maintainer.  However, the application items show under some menu items were incorrect, and showed both the previous and current release versions of the application as shown under Applications. MATE Control Center -> Look and Feel -> Main Menu did not show the same application items.  Where are the text files (as under ~/Desktop/ for the Desktop of a specific user) that are used by Main Menu under MATE kept?  Presumably these can be edited as root and the issues corrected.
